# Redirecting logs to log4j using slf4j  api

Tags: logging, log4j, java.util.logging, slf4j

I have an application  which use  java.util logging and libraries used by this application use different logging frameworks such as  sl4j ,jcl,log4j   .Now I  want to redirect all logs to log4j so  i can take full controll on it.So i add this dependecies to my pom as [this](http://www.slf4j.org/images/legacy.png)  suggest.And log using different loggers as below .**Why   util log not present in output**.

```
               _loggerUtil.log(Level.SEVERE, "*********************Util log**********");
             _loggerCommon.fatal("*********commons log ************");
             _loggerSlf4j.error("**************sl4j log **************");
             _loggerLog4j.fatal("**************log4j log**************");



     2012-01-05 17:11:35,508 [http-8080-3] ERROR com.endersys.itap.ui.module.user.LoginBean - *********commons log ************
^[[19~2012-01-05 17:11:43,561 [http-8080-3] ERROR com.endersys.itap.ui.module.user.LoginBean - **************sl4j log **************
2012-01-05 17:11:44,433 [http-8080-3] FATAL com.endersys.itap.ui.module.user.LoginBean - **************log4j log**************






   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>

      <!--java util to slf4j bridge -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>


        <!--common logging  to slf4j bridge -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>


      <!--sl4j to  log4j bridge-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Isn't there the log4j dependency missing in your pom?

Comment: @martin slf4j-log4j12  dependent to log4j so it is in my class path.

Comment: I am using tomcat  ,can tomcat's logging properties cause this ?

Comment: This question is  what i exactly mention .But accepted answer not help me.It say it related with tomcat logging.properties and should edit its root logger level. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869945/how-to-send-java-util-logging-to-log4j

Comment: @ceki can you suggest a solution.

Comment: org.apache.juli.FileHandler  not exist in my application class path but i see it when debug  .It must supplied by tomcat.

Comment: I try it with jetty but problem not solved.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to go through log4j? Is slf4j not sufficient for you?

Comment: @cdeszaq  it is a legacy application and mostly using util logging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `jul-to-slf4j` it is not enough to simply add the artifact as a dependency. In addition to that, you need to set up the bridge programmatically by calling `SLF4JBridgeHandler.install()` (somewhere during application startup, e.g. in a servlet context listener).

Note 1: `jul-to-slf4j` works well in Tomcat because Tomcat's JUL implementation creates per-application logger namespaces. However, I would not recommend using it on any other application server (except those servers that have a JUL implementation similar to Tomcat's).

Note 2: You should carefully read the Javadoc of SLF4JBridgeHandler to check if you really want to use that (even on Tomcat).