# Logging configuration for Activiti

Tags: java, spring, logging, configuration, activiti

We develop a spring based application also using Aciviti BPM for process management.
Activiti ships with a JobAcquisitionThread handling all TimeBoundary events.
This thread periodically logs DEBUG messages to the console.
Activiti (which uses java.util.logging) seems not to react on our spring framework logging (which uses log4j) config.
How can Activiti be configured to use the same config as spring?

Answer (score 0):

Log4j and java Logging have nothing in common but the gole to log.

So it does not influent the java logging api if you configure somehting with log4j. You need to configue java logging.  This is done by default with an file called `logging.properties`. (And of course it has an other syntax then log4j.)

See this Stack Overflow question: [How to send java.util.logging to log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869945/280244) for some ways how to bridge the log messages,

Answer (score 0):

What about this.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory

class MyClass {

    static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.getClass());

    void methodName() {

        LOG.info("this log goes to log4j configured spring application....")

    }
}
```