# Is it possible to configure the JBOSS AS 7 to use log4j instead of its own logging framework?

Tags: java, logging, jboss, log4j

I'm developing a monitoring app that is supposed to show recent JBOSS AS 7 log entries to the user. I'm using a third party library that can only capture log4j entries so not using log4j is out of question. I am interested in the **entire application server's log** so obviously including log4j in certain web apps won't work for me.

So the problem is I don't know how or even if it is possible to configure JBOSS AS 7 to use log4j instead of its own logging. I googled a lot and didn't find a bridge to do the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about slf4j? You could use the [log4j bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) to link them.  Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869945/how-to-send-java-util-logging-to-log4j)
There's actually some slf4j libraries included in JBoss, but information appears to be sparse on 3rd party logging at the server level.