# How to make log4j not log anything?

Tags: java, debugging, logging, log4j, trace

I tried this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
    INFO="false" debug="false">

    <appender name="foo" class="org.apache.log4j.varia.NullAppender" />
    <root>
        <level value="FATAL" />
        <appender-ref ref="foo" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

but I still get a lot of logs, for example

```
20:09:20.721 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]

20:09:33.202 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Invoking handleMessage on interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassInInterceptor@75ba3523
```

Comment: CXF uses `java.util.logging`, not Log4J.  You will have to configure that too, or [use a bridge](http://stackoverflow.com/q/869945/592139) to send j.u.l output through log4j if you want all the configuration in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CXF uses java.util.logging, not Log4J. You will have to configure that too, or use a bridge to send j.u.l output through log4j if you want all the configuration in one place.