# How to send java.util.logging to log4j2?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I'm working on a project that uses the NetBeans Platform. Under the hood, NetBeans uses the `java.util.logging` framework.

I would like to intercept these log calls by binding `java.util.logging` to `log4j2`. Is this possible?

Previous questions have been asked that are similar, but were specific to `log4j` and not `log4j2`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution:

The NetBeans Platform names logger after the `org.netbeans.*` namespace. To route NetBeans log calls, I simply created a `Handler` and registered it with the `org.netbeans` logger:

```
public class CustomHandler extends Handler
{
    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record)
    {
        // Re-direct log calls here (e.g. send record to Log4j2 logger).
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SecurityException
    {
    }
}
```

Be sure to register the new `Handler` and disable parent loggers if necessary:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("org.netbeans");
logger.addHandler(new CustomerHandler());
logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
```

Answer (score 37):

UPDATE 2014/9/12: From version 2.1, Log4j 2 contain a [JUL bridge](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-jul/index.html) that does not require SLF4J.

No custom code is required. Two things:

1. put the following jars in the classpath:
   log4j-api-2.x, log4j-core-2.x and log4j-jul-2.x.
2. set the system property `java.util.logging.manager` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager` *before any calls are made to LogManager or Logger*

The Log4J2 FAQ page shows the dependencies visually:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#which_jars

Comment: I never wanted to use SLF4J. I have a custom wrapper for Log4j2 acting as the Facade. I found a solution and will be posting it.

Comment: "before any calls are made to LogManager or Logger". This is the biggest disadvantage (though it is due to how hard java.util.logging makes it to provide an alternative implementation). When your project is a dependency of other projects, you cannot easily guarantee that the System property is set at startup. An alternative is to go java.util.logging → SLF4J → Log4j 2; this works even after startup but is probably not very efficient. And it suffers from the problems the SLF4J JUL bridge hat because it is only a JUL Handler, but not a LogManager.

Comment: Log4j 2 actually has a `Log4jBridgeHandler` class similar to SLF4J's one, but it has not been backported to 2.x yet, see [backport pull request](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/437).