# Log loss of a java.util.logging dependency

Tags: java, spring, log4j, log4j2, java.util.logging

I have a dependency that logs in as follows :

```java
import java.util.logging.Logger;

private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
```

And an application that uses the dependency with the following pom :

```json
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.10</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>
```

and the following implementation

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Example.class);
```

and with this configuration it only logs the main application, but if I add this to the pom ....

```json
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

What should I change in the code of the first dependency if I can't use spring to make this work without using log4j 1.2.16 ? What other solutions do I have?

Comment: What makes you think `java.util.logging.Logger` is log4j at all? It is the standard logger shipped with java.

Comment: that's the problem, I don't understand what the relationship is.

Comment: There is no relationship. If you want to use Log4j2 with JUL (Java Util Loggin) see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781026/how-to-send-java-util-logging-to-log4j2

Comment: Spring Boot bridges binds all major logging frameworks to a single backend (see [logging documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging)). You shouldn't add Log4j 1.x or Log4j 2.x Core to your classpath, unless you know what you are doing.