# 3rd party jar logs in tomcat catalina.out

Tags: tomcat, java.util.logging, catalina.out

I am using a library jar with my code. This jar uses the `java.util.Logger` for logging purposes.

In our code we use `log4j2` & write the logs to `project.log` in `tomcat/logs`.

The issue is, the jar's logs are written to tomcat's `catalina.out`. I want these logs to be written to my `project.log` file. This is the file my code's logs are written to.

A quick help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting question

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869945/how-to-send-java-util-logging-to-log4j