# How can I make Guice log using log4j configuration

Tags: java, logging, guice

I'm talking about Guice own messages (those coming from `com.google.inject`). Currently it uses the default config (java.util.logging), so it bypasses all my log4j config, including an handler for Graylog.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send java.util.logging to log4j?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/869945/how-to-send-java-util-logging-to-log4j)

Answer (score 1):

Already asked in this thread: [How to send java.util.logging to log4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/869945/334942)
Many useful suggestions and resources listed there.