# Overwrite java.util.logging.Logger.isLoggable() used by third party library?

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2, slf4j, java.util.logging

The application I'm working on provides logging based on the current user. To achieve this I use the log4j `AbstractFilter` which checks if there is a custom log level for the current user and returns the appropriate result for methods such as `Log.isDebugEnabled()` etc.

Some third party libraries used by my application use `java.util.logging`. I would like to have those log the same way my own logging does. But the `java.util.logging.Logger.isLoggable()` method returns different results than my own logging. Is there some way to overwrite this function with my own logic?

Edit: I use `slf4j` in my application with `log4j2` as the underlying logging framework. I tried to use the java.util.logging ~> slf4j bridge as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869945/how-to-send-java-util-logging-to-log4j?rq=1), but it seems only to affect the `Log` function itself, not the `isLoggable()`.

Answer (score 0):

In java.util.logging you can modify the `isLoggable` behavior by implementing a  [java.util.logging.Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Filter.html) and setting the appropriate [level](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Handler.html#setLevel(java.util.logging.Level)).

From the source code of the [SLF4JBridgeHandler](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/jul-to-slf4j/src/main/java/org/slf4j/bridge/SLF4JBridgeHandler.java) it appears that the publish method is not invoking the [isLoggable](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/Handler.html#isLoggable(java.util.logging.LogRecord)) on the handler.  Because of that, you can't simply install a java.util.logging.Filter to the SLF4JBridgeHandler.

One option would be to wrap the SLF4JBridgeHandler in a proxy handler such as [MemoryHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.logging/java/util/logging/MemoryHandler.html).  This can be setup in a logging.properties file or via code:

```
MemoryHandler h = new MemoryHandler(new SLF4JBridgeHandler(), 1, Level.ALL);
h.setLevel(Level.ALL);
h.setFilter(new CurrentUserFilter()); //Your custom code.
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(h); //Install the bridge manually.
```

Another option is to install log4 filter on all the loggers.  That can be a lot of work if all of the loggers are based on class name an not subsystems.