# Despite using jna.debug_load=true jna library doesn't seem to print the steps of its dll search. What could be wrong?

Tags: java, log4j, jna

We are using a 3rd party library that in turn depends on jna. We have the **jna.debug_load=true** set but we don't see the related logs anywhere. Even after launching our program via cmd prompt and directing the console logs to a file the logs are not to be seen. Not much documentation around this so please help.

Is there a way to get them to show up on our application logs(we use log4j 1.2.x).

Specifically we want to know where it finds jnidispatch.dll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `jna.debug_load=true` setting is for external libraries/DLLs that JNA loads, but not its own native `jnidispatch.dll`.  Per [the JNA FAQ](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/c517796826673ee8bb65d72d10de2f3ac4f57593/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#calling-nativeload-causes-an-unsatisfiedlinkerror) you need `jna.debug_load.jna` for that:

> Set the system property `jna.debug_load=true`, and JNA will print its library search steps to the console. `jna.debug_load.jna` will trace the search for JNA's own native support.

As for the logging itself, JNA logs to `java.util.logging`.  You'll need to redirect that to log4j using one of the solutions outlined in answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869945/how-to-send-java-util-logging-to-log4j)