# Initialize VM arguments to the static variable

Tags: java, log4j, java.util.logging, bridge

I am working on the JUL - Log4j 1.x bridge.
I was follow this steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/4318607.
Everything work fine, when I using VM argument:

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.julbridge.JULBridgeLogManager
```

But I can't using VM arguments, it is some way how to set this classpath like static variable? For in exmple in Main.class

Or somehow set java.util.logging.manager (LogManager class) to JULBridgeLogManager

Comment: You can set system properties with `System.setProperty` **but** it varies a lot *when* those properties are read. I don't know if that specific property will be read/interpreted before execution reaches your main class. If it is, then setting it won't have any observable effect.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I will try, but when I want set my logging manager it will be 

System.setProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.apache.logging.julbridge.JULBridgeLogManager"); 

Or I must somehowe create property?

Comment: Yes, that would be it. There's no distinction between setting and creating.

Comment: @JoachimSauer this is not working for me.

Comment: then the property is apparently read before your code is reached. Seems you need to figure out how to set the system property from the command line after all.

Comment: There must be the way how to do in code :/

Comment: Must there? I'm not sure, but you do you.

Comment: @JoachimSauer it is solved. I did put System.setProperty(...) to the static block and worked well. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used in Main class static block and delete VM arguments and that worked well:

```
static {
    System.setProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.apache.logging.julbridge.JULBridgeLogManager");
}
```